# Connecting Sheets to BigQuery and run the ML PREDICT function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

looking for a way to connect a Biqquery model to google sheets and run the sql to predict based on the inputs on the google sheet. The model already exists and the independent variables exist on the sheet(Range of cells) and output has to be pasted in the column beside these input columns.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#run_query
Looked at the sample code - But this is not dynamic . Looking for something which is dynamic where i can select the range of inputs from the google sheet and paste the output on the same sheet on a column next to input columns.

```
SELECT predicted_BPrices FROM
  ML.PREDICT(MODEL `XXXX',
    (this is the range of values it should consider from the sheet)
```

Basically want to execute the ML.PREDICT function from the Sheets where we pass the independent variables from the sheet and should derive the dependent variable and paste on to the sheets.

Comment: Is there a problem in accomplishing the said goal?

Comment: yes - not able to make the inputs dynamic - Would appreciate if you could provide any leads  on how to achieve this. the sample provided is more of a hardcoded query in the code

Comment: You need to be more specific than that. What have you tried to `make the inputs dynamic`? 1. Easiest:  The query is just a string. In js, You can simply concatenate strings using `+`,but you'll be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. 2. Standard: Use sql parameters [`queryParameters`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#QueryRequest). If all this is really new, you should spend time researching more.